# What is the verb to take out compromises?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I want to describe the action of a person who is fed up with the many compromises he has made and now would like to "remove" these compromises he hates - what is a verb that means "remove compromises"? *Abolish*?

Comment: Do you mean compromises or commitments? (I ask because commitments makes more sense in context, and I know that compromise is a false friend with the word for commitment in at least one major language).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common to say that a person *accepts* or *rejects* a compromise. A person who accepts a compromise could later reject it.

"Abolish" is not combined with "compromise" in place of "reject", according to [Google Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=abolish+compromise%2Creject+compromise%2Cabolish+the+compromise%2Cabolish+any+compromise%2Creject+the+compromise%2Creject+any+compromise&year_start=1900&year_end=2012&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 1):

Some potentially relevant collocations are: *disavow, repent, repudiate, brook no, reject,* and *eschew* although some of them are admittedly future oriented rather than the backwards looking meaning the question implies.

Answer (score 0):

This question is so broad-based there's no definitive answer. The best I can come up with is...

> I'm fed up with always compromising. Henceforth I resolve to be more **assertive**.

Comment: I don't think assertiveness and compromise are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @slim: You must have *compromise* in your blood if you can assert that for the general case! :)

Answer (score 0):

The word that you are looking for doesn’t exist because you can’t take back a compromise once you accepted it. You can redact, renegotiate, reneg, etc… but you can’t unring that bell. You can decide to no longer compromise but you can’t change what you’ve already done. You can only take different future actions than you did in the past. Unless you time travel of course.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That *completely* depends on the (nature of the) compromise that has been made. Additionally your reasoning is faulty since even if your premise is right - compromises can't be "taken back" - it doesn't automatically mean there is no word for it.

Answer (score -4):

[image: Remove Compromises.]

I don't think there is a word for it. Just invent your own.

Comment: Apparently someone has voted against your poster.  Understandable, since the [posters *for* compromise](http://verydemotivational.memebase.com/?s=compromise) are more numerous and better looking.  That issue aside, why not add *decompromise* and *uncompromising* to your answer instead of saying no words apply?

Comment: @jwpat7 thanks. Nice poster, lol. but given the OP's question, I don't think _uncompromising_ or _decompromise_ applies in his case.